# Is there any side effect that if set the dir_source_root to the root directory of the system?

Tags: cobalt

Now the dir_source_root is set to the directory where the cobalt binary laid, and it can not load the local resources(pictures/html pages) in other place expect the cobalt directory, so is there any side effect that if we set the `dir_source_root` to the root directory（eg '/' ） of the system?

```
case kSbSystemPathSourceDirectory:
  if (!GetExecutableDirectory(path, kPathSize)) {
    return false;
  }
  if (SbStringConcat(path, "/content/dir_source_root", kPathSize) >=
      kPathSize) {
    return false;
  }
  break;
```

Answer (score 0):

`dir_source_root` is only used for tests, so is ignored in Gold builds.

But, the broader answer to your question is that opening up more local resources for access would weaken security, so we strongly recommend against it.